# Which file is executed in SQL Server 2005 while backing up data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want a full backup of my SQL Server database using a scheduled batch file. I tried many codes from this website but nothing worked. I just want to know which exe file actually creates the backup so I can directly execute that file from cmd. The codes which I tried are

```
echo -- BACKUP DATABASE --
set /p DATABASENAME=Enter database name:

:: filename format Name-Date (eg MyDatabase.bak)
set BACKUPFILENAME=%CD%\%DATABASENAME%.bak
set SERVERNAME='server name'
echo.

sqlcmd -E -S %SERVERNAME% -d master -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [%DATABASENAME%] TO DISK =           
        N'%BACKUPFILENAME%' WITH INIT , NOUNLOAD, 
        NAME = N'%DATABASENAME% backup', NOSKIP , STATS = 10, NOFORMAT"
```

I also tried this one

```
SqlCmd -E -S sql 'server_name' –Q “BACKUP DATABASE 'db_name' TO DISK=’f:\2014\02\19\db_name.bak’”
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code for above solution

```
echo off
cls
echo -- BACKUP DATABASE --
::set db name
set DATABASENAME=db_name
:: set path and format
set BACKUPFILENAME=PATH\%DATABASENAME%.bak
:: set server name
set SERVERNAME=server_name
echo.
::backup execution
sqlcmd -S %SERVERNAME% -d COFI -U vutagi -P vu1234 -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [%DATABASENAME%] TO DISK = N'%BACKUPFILENAME%' WITH INIT , NOUNLOAD , NAME = N'%DATABASENAME% backup', NOSKIP , STATS = 10, NOFORMAT"
```

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to know which exe file actually creates the backup so I can directly execute that file from cmd.

You have zero understanding how sql server works, right?

The file that runs the backup is the server executable that you can not execute fom the command line - it is basically the exe that already runs to run the database server and waits for a sql command to execute - or 100 at the same time, or 1000, it has no limits.

Sql server is a proper server, not some honky donky small database system tham.

In your above examples:

- SqlCommand is a tool that comes with sql server (it is sqlcommand.exe) and is used t osend a command to the ALREADY RUNING sql server.
- The command you are sending is "BACKUP DATABASEW which tells the already runing server to make up a database. INteresting enough whoever did both has not really spendt a minute thinking.
- I Do not know what you looked up suppsedly on the internet, but the syntax is at

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865(v=sql.100).aspx

for your particular version.

- I suggest you give it a more serious try. Do not use SqlCmd, use the sql management studio. Try to make it working and - cough - if it fails with an exception ,read if and fix what it says. If you do not underrstand the error message ask for help, but hey, without error message we are kind of out of ideas, you know. Once it works transpose it to your batch.
- Note that backup is a command sent ot the server. So your path is not YOUR path, but from the server. Under the server identity. WIthout user mapped network paths.

The proper way from copmmand line is indeed using SqlCmd. Now, I do not know how unsecure you like your servers, but mine require a password. Thus I asume you never bothered to read the sqlcommand syntax. It is at

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx

and I am also quite sure SqlCommand gives you an error output that you just kindly, assuming we all here have the gift of reading your mind - are skipping as totally useless. Read it.

And that sort of makes it complete. Not the nicest answer, but maybe with it you learn to not ignore what is in front of you on your screen - namely error messages. And possibly reading the documentation once in a while instead of copy/pasting "stuff from the internet".

Comment: It means I cannot take a backup using batch file which is running in task schedular

Comment: No, it absolutely does not mean that. People do that successfully - given that there is no agent in the express version that scheules things. All it means is that at one point you have to bite the apple and try to read the documentation, not copy / paste stuff and hope it works.

Comment: can you guide me on how to do it...i don't have any knowledge of sql. Can you give me the code??

Comment: Yes, I can. No, I will not. I believe someone calling himself a programmer should at least try to read and understand the documentation. Or hire someone who can.

Comment: I can understand...just tell me whether this can be done in MSSQL 2005 or not. If possible give me some hint.

Comment: Yes. Again, DOCUMENTATION. Hints? What about LINKS. THere are some in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The backup file is created by SQL server himself, there is no other exe that can do the backup.
When you run your batch file, it connects to SQL and ask SQL Server to backup your database with the BACKUP DATABASE command.

When you use -E flag on SqlCmd command line, it connects to SQL with a trusted connection, so it has to be run under a valid and trusted Windows user, which may not be the case if it is run by a scheduled batch file.
Test your command with a valid SQL login (not a trusted Windows account) in a cmd command line window, by using -U and -P flags to check this.

Another point is that SQL has to have access to your F: drive, ie. the account under which SQL is running has to have access to it , and if this drive is a network drive, the account under which SQL is running must have proper access rights on this network drive (there was also a flag to enable network drive access on old versions of SQL, but I think it is on by default since sql 2008, not sure).

Comment: If you connect using an sql server account, check your serveur can use sql login to connect and not only credential, it's in the property of the server from ssms. If i remember well with sql server 2005 you can access network path unless you are running with another account that local system